# reaching max.print on R

Tags: r, glmnet

I just found a bunch of weather data that I would like to play around with in glmnet in R. First I've been reading and organizing the data in R, and right now I am just trying to look at the raw data of each variable. Unfortunately, each variable has a lot of data and R isn't able to print it all. Is there a way I can view all the raw data in R or just in the file itself? I've tried opening the file in excel to no success. Thanks!

Comment: Try exporting your data from `R` by function `write.table`, `write.csv` or `write.csv2`; then you can open it by Notepad or Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Frequency tables, you can group by segments. 
str() , summary(), table(), pairs(), plots() etc. There are several libraries (such as decr) which facilitate analyzing numerical and factor levels. Let me know if you need help with any.